# Prove that $(p\wedge q)\wedge\lnot(p\vee q)$ is a fallacy

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I am not able to find this answer anywhere its about discrete mathematics.
Plz Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using truth tables? Do you agree with the tables I wrote down?

$$
\begin{array}{cc|c}
p & q & p\wedge q \\
\hline
T & T & T \\
T & F & F \\
F & T & F \\
F & F & F 
\end{array}
\quad\quad\quad
\begin{array}{cc|c}
p & q & p\vee q & \neg(p\vee q) \\
\hline
T & T & T & F \\
T & F & T & F \\
F & T & T & F \\
F & F & F & T 
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2):

A fallacy has to be a ***reasoning*** , that is a sequence of sentences with an inference word such as "therefore" before the last sentence.

What you wrote is a ***sentence*** , an assertion, not a reasoning.

What goes wrong in this sentence is that it is an ***antilogy*** ( or a contradiction or a logical falsehood), meaning a ***formula that is false in all possible cases*** . Antilogy is the contrary of tautology ( a sentence that is true in all possible cases). In the middle lie " contingent sentences" ( sometimes true, sometimes false).

That it is an antilogy can be proved using a truth table ( there are truth tables generators on the web).

Also, one can produce a reasoning to prove that the sentence is contradictory:

(1) suppose the whole sentence is true.

(2) In that case (P&Q) is true, and therefore P is true.

(3) Also, ~ (P OR Q) is true. But that means ( by the definition of the OR-operator) that neither P nor Q is true ( see : DeMorgan's laws).

(4) So P is false.

(5) So P is true ( by (2)) and P is false ( by (4)). Hence a contradiction.

Note : there is also a contradiction as to the truth value of Q; but a single contradiction is enough for the global sentence to be an antilogy.

A ressource : https://courses.umass.edu/phil110-gmh/MAIN/IHome-5.htm